# How do buildings with eco-electricity know their electricity is eco?

Tags: energy, environmental-impact, electricity

Walking around the city centre of Warsaw I saw a poster placed by a construction zone of a new skyscraper. The poster said something along the lines "our building will use electricity from windfarm in XYZ Norway". (I can double check tomorrow.)

I started wondering: how is that possible? I highly doubt that there is special very long cable that runs from Norway to that very building in Warsaw.

I presume that there is some big electricity distribution centre in Poland and that distribution centre buys some energy from that wind farm in Norway. If that's the case, then the poster is just a scam. Let me portray that with an example. Being in Australia and saying: "oh you there, oh come here and taste this amazing lemonade that was made with water specially gathered on the beach in Mexico". Where in fact water was just a regular tap water sourced in Australia.

Looking forward to a conversation :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a scam.

It is certainly true that there is no way to control - or even to know - where a particular "bit" of electricity came from.  But electricity is a generic commodity - within an electric grid it's all the same voltage, same frequency, same phase angle.  None of it is better or worse or different than any other.  Nor is it labeled or tracked in any way.  The grid accepts it from all the generators, and distributes it to all the users.

Some states within the U.S. have deregulated electricity systems, where the generation facilities are owned by various companies, and the utility company handles the transmission and distribution, and billing.  In these areas, customers can choose their supplier based on price or any number of other criteria, which can include the energy source.  The various suppliers all feed their electricity into the grid, and the utility tracks the energy supplied by each generator and energy used by each customer.

The utility also must have a system for reconciling the production by each generator with the consumption by all of their customers, to ensure everyone is meeting their commitments.

In a system like this, each generator will supply the amount of energy that its customers consume - no more and no less.  If one generator is a nuclear power plant, another is a coal plant, and a third is a wind farm, and 20% of the customers buy their power from the third supplier, then the wind farm is supplying the energy needs of 20% of the customers.  If more customers sign up for wind power, the supplier will increase output to meet their new demand, and the other two suppliers will operate their plants at lower power levels.

If the wind stops blowing, the coal and nuclear plants will increase output temporarily.  Then when the wind picks up again, the wind power will be increased to a higher level than their customers demand in order to make up for the power they didn't supply.  In the end it will all balance out.

So are the particular electrons that are used in a building actually supplied exclusively by the wind farm?  No, but the wind farm does feed into the grid the amount of electricity that the building consumes.  And if the building management changes it's mind and decides to use nuclear power instead of wind, the wind plant output will go down and the nuclear plant output will go up by the amount the building uses.

Comment: I see. Let me stick to the milk analogy from the other answer. Let's say there is a dairy cooperative (grid) and restaurant X (building) puts up a poster saying "we use milk from free range cows from local farmers". In fact, restaurant is buying 20% of all milk from the cooperative and the cooperative says that 25% of their milk comes from "from free range cows from local farmers". However sometimes due to cows' tantrums the free range farms can supply only 15% of the demand. In this case the restaurant X uses 15% available and 5% from the robotized cowbarns. Does this make sense?

Comment: That's a different situation, because the milk from different sources is different, so a common distribution system won't work.  But the electricity from different sources is indistinguishable.  There is no way to tell where the electricity in a particular building actually came from, but the total amount of green electricity produced is equal to the total amount of green electricity demanded.

Comment: "third is a wind farm, and 20% of the customers buy their power from the third supplier, then the wind farm is supplying the energy needs of 20% of the customers." -- no it isn't. Hint: think about a windless day! With storage, the theory "in the end it will all balance out" would be correct, but unfortunately, we don't generally have economical electricity storage today. Maybe with hydrogen and pumped storage hydro we could have, but those have traditionally been too expensive to build.

Comment: @juhist "If the wind stops blowing, the coal and nuclear plants will increase output temporarily. Then when the wind picks up again, the wind power will be increased to a higher level than their customers demand in order to make up for the power they didn't supply."

Comment: Yes, but once you emit CO2 into atmosphere, it will stay there. 100% wind power is expected to be 0% carbon emitting electricity but isn't. That's the most important part to understand. Note: I don't oppose wind power, I strongly favor it, but my opinion is that we should start investing massively to offshore wind power where winds are more often strong enough, and also to electricity storage technologies to balance the grid which wind power can't do alone.

Comment: @juhist. I agree wholeheartedly about investing heavily in offshore wind and grid storage.  But I think even without that, the carbon emissions are the same whether you store green electricity in batteries, or use the grid to balance the periods when green power isn't available.

Comment: (2) Imagine that you want to build a new solar-powered factory in a small town.  Suppose the town has its own power plant, and to make the arithmetic simple assume the town uses 100 MegaWatts continually, night and day, supplied by the power plant which generates 100 MW continually.  And assume your new factory will use 1 MW round-the-clock.  Your solar panels will produce 2 MW for 12 hours every day, and nothing during the other 12 hours.

Comment: (3) During the day you generate 2 MW of power, consume 1 MW, and feed the other 1 MW into a battery.  At night you draw 1 MW out of the battery.  Meanwhile, the town power plant continues to generate 100 MW continually and is unaffected by your factory.

Comment: (4) Now imagine that something breaks and you are unable to use the battery, so you instead feed the surplus power into the grid during the day, and draw out of the grid at night.  For 12 hours during the day you feed 1 MW into the grid, while the town continues to consume 100 MW.  So the power plant now only has to generate 99 MW during the day.

Comment: (5) Then at night you draw 1 MW from the grid, while the town continues to draw 100 MW, so the power plant generates 101 MW at night.  The average power generated by the power plant is still 100 MW, just as it was while you were using the battery and not connected to the grid.  And since the daily average power generation is the same, the daily average CO2 emitted is also the same.

Answer (score 2):

> our building will use electricity from windfarm in XYZ Norway

No it doesn't.

Firstly, all electricity in the grid is mixed. It is completely impossible to say that a particular building gets its electricity from a particular generation site.

Theoretically, an electrical engineer could calculate how much the load at every generation site increases if a new electricity consumer is added to a certain location of the grid. However, the answer to this is very clear: a consumer uses electricity mostly from nearby generation sites, and very little from far-away generation sites.

Also, what if the connection of the wind farm XYZ to the grid fails? Does the building have a contract that says the building will automatically be isolated from the grid to prevent it from using electricity from other sources? Most likely it doesn't. Because it doesn't, it uses electricity from whatever generation sites may be available.

Furthermore, even a claim that a particular building uses "wind electricity" is bogus. What if it's a windless day? Do the lights in the building turn off then? No they don't. And because they don't, the building doesn't really use "wind electricity".

Usually claims about using "wind electricity" are made in the following way: a building consumes X kWh, and it buys X kWh from wind power. However, those X kWh:s are generated and consumed at different times, and since the grid doesn't yet have a good and plentiful way of storing energy deployed in large enough scale (today the largest-deployed storage is hydropower but we don't have enough of it), it's actually very likely that even though X kWh:s of wind power  were generated, the building partially used fossil fuel generated electricity.

Maybe someday pumped storage hydro will be built in large enough scale to mountainous areas. [A paper in Nature Communications](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-14555-y) claims that we have enough suitable sites. Also, hydrogen can be stored underground. The problems of hydrogen however are that the round-trip efficiency from electricity to hydrogen to electricity back again is about 35%, i.e. not very good, and that the turbine / combustion engine power plants that convert it back to electricity are needed so rarely but still have to be paid for, that you can expect price of 200-300 USD/MWh for hydrogen electricity.

One solution that is available near the equator is solar cells and lithium ion batteries. For wind power, battery storage doesn't work since there can easily be 2-3 consecutive weeks with poor wind, but solar power is more consistent and even during cloudy days you get about one fourth of the energy you would get from a sunny day, whereas on a windless day you would get nothing from wind power. So you can charge a battery daily and discharge it nightly. Far away from the equator, the problem is that there's so little solar power available during winter, so solar + batteries doesn't work far away from the equator.

So you're right. The claim is a scam.

However, if there was a special cable from the wind farm to the building, then it wouldn't be a scam. But then if the one single cable gets damaged or if winds at the wind farm are poor, then the building would experience a blackout.

Comment: Thanks a million for this elaborate answer! It is awesome. 

I went to the place again and the poster says (in Polish) what's below.

"Officie building The Bridge will be power green energy coming from solar farms Ghelamco. Our goal is to make the company and projects energetically neutral via solar farms in 2025 at the latest."

What do you think is the goal behind the poster? Do they really wanna scam people or they just don't know how it all works? They wanna follow the eco-trends wave? 

We both now know how it works, how would rephrase such a poster?